# Use a form with a custom __init__ in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I use the code below to add a custom form in Django Admin:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyForm
```

However, the form has an overridden constructor:

```
def __init__(self, author, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.author = author
```

How could I pass the Admin current user to the form constructor?

Answer (score 6):

change your `MyAdmin` class like this:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyForm

    def get_form(self, request, **kwargs):
        form = super(MyAdmin, self).get_form(request, **kwargs)
        form.current_user = request.user
        return form
```

You can now access the current user in your `forms.ModelForm` by accessing `self.current_user`.

```
def __init__(self, author, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.author = author
    # access to current user by self.current_user
```

Comment: But then I need to remove the "author" parameter from the __init__ method otherwise I get an error. I would like to keep the parameter.

Comment: @Ivan you can pass `author` parameter to form `__init__` in `def get_form`

Comment: Could you add an example to see how to add `author` to the `__init__` method from `get_form`?