# How to pass an extra argument to django admin custom form?

Tags: django, django-admin

As you know we can define a ModelForm and then replace add and change forms by setting form attribute in modelAdmin class. for example:

```
class FooAdminForm(django.forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Foo

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(FooAdminForm, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)


class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = FooAdminForm
```

in a simple view we can initialize a form object and pass extra arguments to **init** function of the form. something like this:

```
def my_view(request):
    form = FooAdminForm(p1='aaa', p2='bbb')
```

and then in the **init** function we can access these parameter.

```
self.p1 = kwargs.pop('p1')
self.p2 = kwargs.pop('p2')
```

but how can I pass arguments to modelAdmin form? I can only pass form class to modelAdmin form attribute, and I can't initialize it like in views.

I found a solution on stackoverflow here:

[Use a form with a custom __init__ in Django Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959934/use-a-form-with-a-custom-init-in-django-admin)

but it adds a dynamic attribute to form object, which I think is a little hackish. Is there a better or formal way for doing this?

Comment: Did you ever find a better way?

Comment: Using `functools.partial` is better than setting a class attribute, but still hacky :(

Comment: @djvg this answer also solve the problem and has many upvotes.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683689/django-access-request-object-from-admins-form-clean

Comment: `but it adds a dynamic attribute to form object` — that is the correct way to do that.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking around for a solution to this, and found a kinda-elegant solution in Django's issue tracker:

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    Form = super().get_form(request, obj=None, **kwargs)
    return functools.partial(Form, user=request.user)
```

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27240#comment:9

So if you're using a custom form, you can simply pass it to `super().get_form()` using `kwargs`

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    kwargs['form'] = FooAdminForm
    Form = super().get_form(request, obj=None, **kwargs)
    return functools.partial(Form, user=request.user)
```

Comment: on django 4.0.4 the method receives 4 params: `get_form(self, request, obj=None, change=False, **kwargs)`,  but it worked :D

Answer (score -1):

Because `ModelAdmin.get_form` does not quite behave the same as `FormView.get_form`, you need to be a bit sneaky:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = FooAdminForm

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form_class = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        class Form(form_class):
            def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                kwargs.update(foo='bar')
                super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return Form
```

Comment: The error is `modelform_factory() got an unexpected keyword argument 'foo'` because `get_form` initializes a [modelform_factory](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c459a4661b2e96b53d3784c76e1fd5651b8cdc4a/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L702) and provides a [`ModelForm` class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c459a4661b2e96b53d3784c76e1fd5651b8cdc4a/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1555), not instance. [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform-factory-function)

Comment: Ah, my bad. `ModelAdmin.get_form` behaves differently to `View.get_form`...

Comment: You might be able to use `functools.partial` to add the keyword argument to the result of `super().get_form(...)`, but that's getting a bit hacky...

Comment: Not working for me, I get AttributeError: Form' object has no attribute 'get'. On Django 2.2, but I don't think that makes the difference.

Comment: gabn88: Are you sure you typed it in correctly? There is no `.get()` call in my answer, only `.get_form`.