# Is it possible to pass extra data to the django admin form as argument?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I have a Django model with the implemented Django admin interface and I want to display the form for the model. If the form displays only the attributes of the model, it's a simple task. My problem is that I would like to change the fields of the form depending on the user authenticated. **Is there any way how to pass extra data (user) as an argument to the ModelForm **init** function from the admin?** I found some tutorials, but their implementation worked only for basic views, not for the Admin implementation.

I have also tried to pass an extra argument to the admin get_form() function, but it is not possible to. I get the error that an unexpected argument was provided.

My Form:

```py
Class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
    model = Profile

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        interests = ProfileInterest.objects.filter(
            user=user # HERE I WOULD LIKE TO ACCESS THE USER (request.user)
        )
        for i in range(len(interests) + 1):
            field_name = 'interest_%s' % (i,)
            self.fields[field_name] = forms.CharField(required=False)
            try:
                self.initial[field_name] = interests[i].interest
            except IndexError:
                self.initial[field_name] = “”
        # create an extra blank field
        field_name = 'interest_%s' % (i + 1,)
        self.fields[field_name] = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

I'm trying to filter the **ProfileInterest** queryset by the user and then displaying them as form fields. I need to pas the user instance somehow to the form from the Admin definition.

Comment: Yes it's possible, can you share your form with the dynamic fields?

Comment: I have added the definition

Comment: Can you share the `Profile` and `ProfileInterest` model? Could the dynamic fields be replace by an inline?

Comment: I just need to know, how to pass data from admin to the form. I'm not looking for another complete solution. Thank you.

Comment: You might want to check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959934/use-a-form-with-a-custom-init-in-django-admin

Comment: Awesome, it works. Thank you @ger.s.brett !